# Old PhotoRate 2.0 designed to work on PHP 4 Does not now work

Tags: php, html, mysql, obsolete

I have built a much larger script off this original script called PhotoRate 2.0
it was originally designed for php 4  and has worked up until my provider recently
upgraded their php version.  I have the original Script here.

The first part is the config.php

```
<?
####################################
#        PhotoRate v2.0
#      Nuked Web Services
#    http://www.nukedweb.com/
####################################

#These 4 blank variables MUST be filled in with your
#MySQL information before you canstart.


$sqlhost = "";
$sqllogin = "";
$sqlpass = "";
$sqldb = "";
$table = "photorate";

#Voting Options - Change these to suit your purpose for PhotoRate
$option_a = "Disgusting!";
$option_b = "Pretty Bad!";
$option_c = "It's OK.";
$option_d = "Pretty Nice!";
$option_e = "Oh YEAH!";

#Color bars - These specify the colors of the vote results bars on each page.
$optcolor_a = "#FF0000";
$optcolor_b = "#0033FF";
$optcolor_c = "#00CC66";
$optcolor_d = "#FFFF33";
$optcolor_e = "#9966FF";

#This specifies the maximum size (in bytes) for uploaded pictures.
$maxsize = "100000";

#This needs not to be edited. It's the code to connect to MySQL. :)
$db = mysql_connect($sqlhost, $sqllogin, $sqlpass);

mysql_select_db($sqldb, $db);

?>
```

The Next part is index.php

```
<?
####################################
#        PhotoRate v2.0
#      Nuked Web Services
#    http://www.nukedweb.com/
####################################

include "./config.php";

if ($voteid && $voteval){
if ($voteval=="1") $vfield = "vote_a";
if ($voteval=="2") $vfield = "vote_b";
if ($voteval=="3") $vfield = "vote_c";
if ($voteval=="4") $vfield = "vote_d";
if ($voteval=="5") $vfield = "vote_e";
$sql = "select $vfield from $table where id='$voteid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$resrow = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$curval = $resrow[0];
$curval++;
$sql = "update $table set $vfield = '$curval' where id='$voteid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$sql = "select id from $table where id < '$voteid' order by id desc LIMIT 0,1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
    print "You've reached the end of the pictures. <a href='index.php'>Click  here</a> to go back to the beginning.";
    exit;
}
$resrow = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$id = $resrow[0];
}

 if (!$id){
$sql = "select max(id) from $table";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Failed: $sql - ".mysql_error());
$resrow = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$id = $resrow[0];
if (!$id){
    print "No pictures have yet been submitted. <a href='new.php'>Click   here</a> to submit one.";
    exit;
}
 }

 $sql = "select email,aim,icq,yahoo,homepage,vote_a,vote_b,vote_c,vote_d,vote_e,picfile,dt from $table where id='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Failed: $sql - ".mysql_error());
$resrow = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$email = $resrow[0];
$aim = $resrow[1];
$icq = $resrow[2];
$yahoo = $resrow[3];
$homepage = $resrow[4];
$vote_a = $resrow[5];
$vote_b = $resrow[6];
$vote_c = $resrow[7];
$vote_d = $resrow[8];
$vote_e = $resrow[9];
$picfile = $resrow[10];
$dtf = $resrow[11];
$dta = split(" ", $dtf);
$created = $dta[0];

if ($email) $btns .= "<a href='mailto:$email'><img src='images/icon-email.gif'  border='0'></a> ";
if ($aim) $btns .= "<a href='aim:goim?screenname=$aim'><img src='images/icon-aim.gif' border='0'></a> ";
if ($icq) $btns .= "<a href='http://wwp.icq.com/scripts/contact.dll?msgto=$icq'><img src='images/icon-icq.gif' border='0'></a> ";
if ($yahoo) $btns .= "<a href='ymsgr:sendim?".$yahoo."'><img src='images/icon-yahoo.gif' border='0'></a> ";
if ($homepage) $btns .= "<a href='$homepage' target='pr_".$id."'><img src='images/icon-home.gif' border='0'></a> ";

if ($vote_a > $biggestnum) $biggestnum = $vote_a;
if ($vote_b > $biggestnum) $biggestnum = $vote_b;
if ($vote_c > $biggestnum) $biggestnum = $vote_c;
if ($vote_d > $biggestnum) $biggestnum = $vote_d;
if ($vote_e > $biggestnum) $biggestnum = $vote_e;
if (!$biggestnum) $biggestnum = $vote_a;
$vp_a = 0;
$vp_b = 0;
$vp_c = 0;
$vp_d = 0;
$vp_e = 0;
if ($vote_a!=0) $vp_a = intval(($vote_a/$biggestnum)*100);
if ($vote_b!=0) $vp_b = intval(($vote_b/$biggestnum)*100);
if ($vote_c!=0) $vp_c = intval(($vote_c/$biggestnum)*100);
if ($vote_d!=0) $vp_d = intval(($vote_d/$biggestnum)*100);
if ($vote_e!=0) $vp_e = intval(($vote_e/$biggestnum)*100);

$template = join("", file("./template.html"));
$template = str_replace("[contactbuttons]", $btns, $template);
$template = str_replace("[picture]", "<img src='pics/".$picfile."'>", $template);
$template = str_replace("[voteoptions]", "<form name='form1' method='post' action=''>   <input type='radio' name='voteval' value='1'>$option_a <br><input type='radio'   name='voteval' value='2'>$option_b<br><input type='radio' name='voteval'  value='3'>$option_c<br><input type='radio' name='voteval' value='4'>$option_d<br><input   type='radio' name='voteval' value='5'>$option_e<br><input type='hidden' name='voteid'   value='$id'><input type='submit' value='Vote!'></form>", $template);
$template = str_replace("[voteresults]", "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td width='500' align='right' valign='top'><font size='-3' face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'>$option_a ($vote_a Votes)<br>$option_b ($vote_b Votes)<br>$option_c ($vote_c Votes)<br>$option_d ($vote_d Votes)<br>$option_e ($vote_e Votes)</font></td><td width='503'> <table width='$vp_a' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' height='13'><tr> <td bgcolor='$optcolor_a'><font size='-3'  face='Verdana'>&nbsp;</font></td></tr></table><table width='$vp_b' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' height='13'><tr> <td bgcolor='$optcolor_b'><font size='-3' face='Verdana'>&nbsp;</font></td></tr></table><table width='$vp_c' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' height='13'><tr> <td bgcolor='$optcolor_c'><font size='-3' face='Verdana'>&nbsp;</font></td></tr></table><table width='$vp_d' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' height='13'><tr> <td bgcolor='$optcolor_d'><font size='-3' face='Verdana'>&nbsp;</font></td></tr></table><table width='$vp_e' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' height='13'><tr> <td bgcolor='$optcolor_e'><font size='-3' face='Verdana'>&nbsp;</font></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><font size='-3' face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'>Powered By <a   href='http://nukedweb.memebot.com/' target='_nukedweb'>PhotoRate</a></font>", $template);

print $template;
?>
```

**The problem is it does not increment the pictures at all ?
It did and the older php and nothing changed in the script.**

I have checked errors and get one that split() should be changed 
I use it as in $dta = split(" ", $dtf)  any one show me the change
I should do that would be cool.  Other errors just say Variable not defined
for many of the variables but I believe that is because error reporting has been
turned on.

Thanks in Advance...  I have stared at this and too long... I am stumped.

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted appears to make extensive use of the `register_globals` feature. The default for this in PHP before 4.2 was `on`, but the whole feature was removed in PHP 5.4.

The effect of `register_globals` was to make querystring parameters available as variables in your code automatically. With it removed, any communication between the pages can't happen unless you change the code.

You'll need to look at what variables are being passed in the querystring and add lines for each variable to the top of your code like this:

```
$variable = $_GET['variable'];
```

However, there are other problems brewing. This code is using `mysql_*()` functions to interact with a database. These functions are themselves deprecated and will be removed soon. You should rework the code to use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO` instead. There is also the capacity for SQL Injection attacks because of the way the querystring variables are being used.

Fixing the code to modern standards is not going to be a straightforward task. It's possible, but you might do better to get some newer code.